# I never get in the callback function, nodejs just stops

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I always used nodejs together with express, but now I try to run the following script in nodejs (just by calling in the terminal "node myscript.js")

postModel is a mongoose model, doing a query on a mongodb.

```
'use strict'
var postModel = require(__dirname + '/../model/post').postModel;
myfunction();
function myfunction() {
    console.log("before call");
    postModel
        .find({isArchived: false})
        .exec(function(err,result){
            console.log("result is ok")
        })
};
```

so what I don't understand is why I never see "result is ok" in my terminal.

I also tried this with the async and wait.for library, but also there my script just stops before the async function is executed and a result is returned.

I think I just miss something in what I am doing, but no idea what...

Comment: There is probably a problem with your model, and it's crashing before you retrieve the result

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, no if I use this code connected to an endpoint in express, the code executes just fine.

Comment: hi you were right as well... it was indeed the problem that I was simply not connected to my database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`mongoose.connect()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) to actually connect to a database.

Otherwise, Mongoose will queue your query internally and wait for a connection before issuing the query. However, since that connection never comes (because `mongoose.connect()` wasn't called), the queue is never processed, your query is never issued, and hence its callback will never get called.

Comment: thanks! now that I know what to look for, it is indeed literally in their FAQ...

Q. My save() callback never executes. What am I doing wrong?

A. All collection actions (insert, remove, queries, etc.) are queued until the connection opens.